Create line chart using d3.js
I want to create a line chart for the following data  in powerbi custom visual d3.js



Student name
Marks




Jasmine
45


Oliver
33


Maya
11


Ethan
66


Sophia
77


Lucas
8


Ava
88


Clara
11



I've tried follwing  code , but I'm getting a blank visual.Are there any latest resources for creating visuals in d3.js.
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};

// Calculate the width and height of the chart area
var width = pbi.width - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = pbi.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Define x and y scales
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1, 0.2);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g") // Append a 'g' element for grouping
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


pbi.dsv(type, function(Names) {
    // Set the domain for x and y scales based on data
    x.domain(Names.map(function(d) { return d.Name; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(Names, function(d) { return d.Marks; })]);
  
  
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Append y axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Append bars
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Name); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Marks); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Marks); })
        .style("fill", pbi.colors[0]); 
 
  
});

function type(d) {
    d.Marks = +d.Marks;
    return d;
}


Why not the native line chart or Deneb if you need more customisation?

only d3.js is allowed to use in our organization. So trying in d3 itself

feeling it is bit complicated, and didn't found much resources online

That doesn;t maje sense. D3.js isn't certified whereas Deneb is which means not a security issue.

Even I don't have any idea about that why it is like that, that's why I'm trying in d3 only
